# How common are broken ASTs?

Tags: eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

During development in Eclipse, how common is it for the AST that the JDT returns to clients to be broken somehow? And in what ways are they sometimes broken?

I imagine obvious things like missing imports, but are there also cases where the code compiles, but the JDT-AST is still broken, or is this AST also the input to the actual compilers?

Comment: What's your definition of "broken"?  Null pointer to tree? Some node has null children?  Some node isn't a valid Java node?  The syntax of the program represented by the tree is simply illegal?  The syntax is legal, but there are variables outside of the scope?  The program is wrong according to the compiler? The program is legal but blows up or hangs when run?   FWIW, most good parsers (I assume JDT has one) will build ASTs that syntactically legal from syntactically legal source, but don't check the language semantics; thats a step beyond parsing.   I think JDT does semantic checking, too.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by syntax and semantic here, is, e.g, type correctness semantic according to your definition or syntax?

Comment: Syntax should be pretty clear: the program is composed of elements that don't violate the BNF grammar.  Semantics are the rest of the constraints imposed by the language definition ("you can't use an identifier i in a scope in which it isn't visible").

Answer (score 0):

If the code has compile errors the AST returned by JDT's API will have 'malformed nodes'. 
If the code compiles then the AST should correspond perfectly with the code. There could be bugs but this area is tested fairly well.

Comment: any clue how "bad" the code can become before the malformed nodes lead to false positives in the error detection? Meaning that sometimes your code suddenly turns red at weird spots because something is pretty broken in another part of the code? Does this only happen with missing imports and wrong bracketing or are there other cases too?

Comment: Syntax errors can confuse the compiler, e.g. incomplete statements while you are typing code.